# can i set a mesh's uv map for a specific image only?

Tags: texturing, uv

I have a model that I want to manually increase the texture resolution of. since it was made for a game the textures aren't the best. my idea was I could manually remake the diffuse map but then I would have to manually remake every single map and I can't do that. I figured if I could have a UV map for the diffuse map and a separate UV map for every other texture then I could get away with only making the diffuse texture. I also tried to use ai to increase texture resolution with stable diffusion but that didn't work at all. ***so basically I have 2 questions; can I have multiple UV maps for the same mesh but different textures? and what is the best way to increase texture resolution*** (current texture is 256x256)

Comment: Unless you're using some kind of machine learning algorithm, you can't upscale an image texture. You can downscale if you have say a 8k resolution to 4k, but not the other way around. Lost data remains lost.

Comment: @Emir alright that's fine I'm ok with making it from scratch but is there a way to edit the UV map of the object only for a specific image map?

Comment: You don't need a separate UV map for a different resolution, as UV coordinates are multiplied by image's width and height. Your second question is not a good fit for this website, it's opinion based and it depends...